# Need help with Cartesian Tensor/Index notation proofs

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus, vectors, proof-explanation

Here's the first one. I thought it was as simple as multiplying f by the Kronecker Delta (which gives the identity matrix with f's instead of 1's), but now I'm not sure if the δ term is actually supposed to be the Dirac delta? I know nothing about the Dirac delta, as it's not covered in my book or my lectures. What would be the best way to prove this?

∇ ⋅ (f **δ**) = ∇f

For this final one, I'm having a similar issue with the last one. I don't know if the δ term is Kronecker or Dirac, nor do I know what to do with it. I'm also not familiar with using the : rule, although I've been familiarizing myself with it online.

**δ** : ∇**a** = ∇ ⋅ **a**

Answer (score 0):

Indeed $\delta$ is the identity matrix, its entries given by the Kronecker delta. With implicit summation over repeated indices your equations are $\partial_i (f\delta_{ij})=\partial_j f,\,\delta_{ij}\partial_i a_j =\partial_i a_i$. Note $:$ takes the trace of a matrix product.

Comment: Isn't that just rewriting the identity in the proper notation? It doesn't really explain how you get to that. Since I am trying to do the proof, I would like to understand the intermediate steps

Comment: @Jasen Step 1: where $\cdot$ appears, an index repeats. Step 2: balance all remaining indices. Step 3: if the result isn't easily proven, you know you made a mistake.

Comment: I will think that over and try to figure it out. Does that just apply to the first equation? Or does it also apply to the second? I am trying to figure out what you mean by "an index repeats". Do you mean if i is equal to j in the Kronecker delta? If so, I don't understand what it takes to "balance the remaining indices". Sorry I'm not better at this, but I really appreciate all your help! This stuff is so convoluted

Comment: @Jasen It'll work for both. What I meant was there will be an index that appears twice because of the $\cdot$. In neither case would it be on $\delta$ though. In an $n$-dimensional space, $\delta_{ii}=n$.